# Forgot lock pattern in One plus one phone

Tags: lock-screens, data-recovery, locked-out, oneplus-one

My girlfriend set a pattern lock for One plus one phone and she cannot remember the pattern now. I have a very sensitive data and also many valued pics. kindly help me recover the data or remove the lock.

Please please please please help me. I am in big trouble without the data.

I spoke to One plus customer service rep, they said reset is the only option. But i will loose the data and I can't afford to loose the data.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! You're by far not the first to ask this question. Please see our [locked-out tag-wiki](/tags/locked-out/info), and especially follow up to [this post](/a/35848/16575) for a collection of possible approaches. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will need [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) for this method.

Because Android does not allow adb connection if the device was not unlocked, you can't access adb from the system itself in your situation. Instead, you will need some recovery that gives you adb access.
[twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp) (Team Win Recovery Project)'s recovery gives you adb access. What you want to do is install TWRP on the OnePlus One (bacon) device; you can download the img file from [here](https://dl.twrp.me/bacon/).

Next, you want to make sure that you unlocked the [bootloader](/questions/tagged/bootloader). If you didn't beforehand then you're out of luck¹ – but if the device is unlocked, boot into [fastboot](/questions/tagged/fastboot) (hold <kbd>volume up</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd> until the "fastboot" screen appears). You then could install TWRP by typing this command:

option 1 (*installing* TWRP to the device):

```
fastboot flash recovery [TWRP.img on your computer]
```

or option 2 (just booting it once without installing):

```
fastboot boot [TWRP.img on your computer]
```

then reboot to recovery (only option 1 – option 2 does that automatically).

Now, to remove the pattern lock, run `adb shell rm /data/system/gesture.key`, and reboot the device.

---

¹ If you havn't unlocked the device yet, unlocking it will wipe everything (including the pattern lock) so adb wont matter. If you do want to unlock the device (your own risk):

1. reboot to bootloader
2. type in `fastboot oem unlock`.

that's it. hope it helped you.

Comment: edited the post hope it helps, one plus one uses a custom rom its etheir CyanogenOS(which is already dead) or Oxygen. these are custom ROMs which are built from stock android,which means they will work like any other device. fun fact: 1+1 phones bootloader are much easier to unlock the other brands ones.

Comment: Thanks, Nadav – that looks great now! Applied some formatting to make it easier to read (and find related information via our tags), and will clean up comments now. A fact that's still missing (but available via the linked tag) are the requirements of a computer with the ADB tools installed, by the way – but as said, that can be found easily via the [adb tag wiki](/tags/adb/info) ;)