# One Plus One broken screen recover data (google auth codes)

Tags: data-recovery, broken-screen, locked-out, oneplus-one, google-authenticator

I unfortunately broke my screen for the second time on my One Plus One. And it seems that my first repair somehow was not totally good, since when I booted it up with the replacement screen, the bottom of the screen was not working.
That makes me unable to unlock my pattern and access my precious data on my phone (the most important being a Google Auth code, and I can't find the recovery codes for that one).

The phone is running Cyanogen, so I tried to access it with adb :
 - I booted the One Plus One in recovery mode by holding the Volume - and Power buttons.
 - then I selected Reboot to bootloader
 - Finally i connected it to my laptop (running Archlinux) and typed `fastboot boot twrp.img` and got the result `Device not unlocked cannot boot`

I was mostly following [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/173631/304793).

So, my question is, am I really out of luck and my data irremediably lost since the phone is locked ? Or is there workarounds with adb ? I only need to recover the data, not really to restore the phone.

For clarity, the phone still works, except for that lower part of the screen.

It seems there is some things I could do but I'm not really sure how :
 - Simulating a mouse with my computer to unlock the pattern grid
 - Extract the disk (but I'm not really sure what the connector type is...)

Thanks in advance if you have any leads.

Comment: Have you tried to resize the display with ADB?

Comment: Your phone has OTG support. Why don't you buy an OTG cable and use it with a mouse to unlock the device and do what you can with a touch. Also, you can resize the screen and change density if you still want to continue using the phone. In that case, follow [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/115652/96277). But I suggest using OTG first and be done with the data you need.

Comment: @VannTen In the title you mention the Google Authenticator. Recovery/backup of the authentication codes is by design not intended. Therefore you should always collect the authenticator backup codes and e.g. print them.

Comment: @Robert I did print them, and I have moste of them, but there is one account of which I can not find the codes. (Not to mention some sites provides the 2FA setup but no recovery codes).

Comment: @Firelord
I'm gonna see if I can find that indeed...

Comment: Is the bootloader unlocked? Did you tick to enable OEM unlocking within developer settings? Your lock screen does not prevent you from doing stuff through the bootloader.

Comment: It is not, that's why I cannot boot a custom recovery. If I understand correctly, I could unlock it with `fastboot oem unlock`, but that would erase my data.